# ASP.NET Core MVC app returns empty response on email confirmation link click

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-6.0

I have developed a small ASP.NET Core 6 MVC app using the identity framework. Everything works fine when I run it on my development machine running Windows 10 from inside Visual Studio. Including the confirmation links.

The problem starts here: I have deployed the app to a linux ubuntu server. The app is running and can be viewed with the browser. I register with my email. The confirmation link is generated and mailed to the user just fine. Everything works until here.

Once I click on the confirmation link, I get an empty response in the browser. What am I doing wrong? Can I somehow enable logging and see what's happening? Am I maybe missing something from the .NET Core runtime on the linux machine? I have just published the app to a folder from Visual Studio and copied everything over to the server, gave permissions etc..

Also what I have found out is that controllers that have the attribute `[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]` or any other `Authorize` attribute return an empty response.

Thanks in advance

update 1:

found out the cause is haproxy which sits in front and handles the https connections, then redirects to kestrel on its http port. The app thinks it should generate urls with http:// instead of https:// When i modify the confirmation link to use https, it works. Can I somehow tell the site that it should generate links with https? Also for redirects?

Comment: What is your authentication mechanism ? You can increase the log verbosity by lowering the threshold in the appsettings.json file.

Comment: Thanks @ArwynFr , i found the cause of the problem. I have haproxy in front which is handling the https connections and redirecting to the http endpoint of kestrel. Now the confirmation links generated have http in their url instead of https which is causing the errors. Still i don't know how to fix this... the app thinks it should generate http urls instead of https

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the middleware doesn't know the request originated from an https connection which was handed over by a proxy.
Two steps had to be performed.

1st:

Tell haproxy (the reverse proxy) to create X-Forwarded-Proto and X-Forwarded-From headers when forwarding requests to kestrel

2nd:

add this code to Program.cs which tells the middleware to handle X-Forwarded-Proto and X-Forwarded-From:

```
builder.Services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
{
    options.ForwardedHeaders = 
        ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto;
});
```

and

```
app.UseForwardedHeaders();
```

The exact steps for the second part are described by microsoft here
[Configure ASP.NET Core to work with proxy servers and load balancers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer?source=recommendations&view=aspnetcore-7.0)